# Is it possible to sort items in FSO with classic asp?

Tags: asp-classic

Im using the following code on an old IIS machine to generate XML for a mobile app I have built for android and ios devices... it works, but I am now wanting to figure out how I would go about SORTING by date last modified so the list has the NEWEST files at top... my question is, based on how I have my code structured below,

is this possible with my existing code  ( sorting 'x' somehow? )?

```vbs
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%Response.ContentType = "text/xml"%>
<%Response.AddHeader "Content-Type","text/xml"%>

<songlist>
<%
dim fs,fo,x
dim i
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'point to a specific folder on the server to get files listing from...
set fo=fs.GetFolder(Server.MapPath("./songs"))
i = -1


for each x in fo.files
'loop through all the files found, use var 'i' as a counter for each...
i = i + 1
'only get files where the extension is 'mp3' -- we only want the mp3 files to show in list...
if right(x,3) = "mp3" then   
%>

<song>
<songid><%=i%></songid>
<name><%= replace(replace(x.Name, "-", " "), ".mp3", "")%></name>
<filename><%=x.Name%></filename>
<datemodified><%=x.DateLastModified%></datemodified>
</song>


<% 
end if 
next

set fo=nothing
set fs=nothing
%>
</songlist>
```

Comment: Not without introducing new techniques - the FileSystemObject.Files property doesn't support any sorting semantics.

You should be able to get something equivalent working in ASP.Net WebAPI in under half an hour, though. I'd strongly suggest avoiding the route of getting things marshaled into an array of script objects and sorting them then emitting XML this way in classic ASP (though you could do it).

If you must stick to classic ASP.... try switching to JScript.

Comment: @Tetsujin no Oni - yeah, I figured FSO would be limited in that regard after doing more research since posting the question... I'm creating an array in the mobile app itself before presenting in the UI so I'll try sorting there instead.

Comment: how about posting this as an answer instead ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily sort anything in VBScript using an old time trick known as Recordset Sorting. Code below is fully working and idea is taken from good old asp101 site, R.I.P ([archive link](http://web.archive.org/web/20110905051845/http://www.asp101.com/samples/dir_list_sort.asp))

```vbs
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<% Option Explicit %>
<%Response.ContentType = "text/xml"%>
<%Response.AddHeader "Content-Type","text/xml"%>
<songlist>
<%
Const adVarChar = 200
Const adInteger = 3
Const adDate = 7

Dim objFSO, oFolder, oFile
Dim fileCounter, objRS
Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'point to a specific folder on the server to get files listing from...
Set oFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Server.MapPath("."))
Set objFSO = Nothing

'create a disconnected recordset
Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'append proper fields
objRS.Fields.Append "Name", adVarChar, 255
objRS.Fields.Append "DateLastModified", adDate
objRS.Open

'loop through all the files found, add to the recordset
For Each oFile in oFolder.Files
    objRS.AddNew
    objRS.Fields("Name").Value = oFile.Name
    objRS.Fields("DateLastModified").Value = oFile.DateLastModified
Next
Set oFolder=nothing

'sort and apply:
objRS.Sort = "DateLastModified DESC"
objRS.MoveFirst

fileCounter = 0
'loop through all the records:
Do Until objRS.EOF %>
<song>
<songid><%=fileCounter%></songid>
<filename><%=objRS("Name")%></filename>
<datemodified><%=objRS("DateLastModified")%></datemodified>
</song><% 
    fileCounter = fileCounter + 1
    objRS.MoveNext()
Loop
objRS.Close
Set objRS = Nothing
%>
</songlist>
```

(I removed some bits when testing locally, you can of course add them back)

Worth to mention that Recordset sorting is very efficient, when I did custom benchmarks years ago it proved to work fast even with thousands of items.

Comment: wow, this is cool... thanks.  I lived and breathed on the old asp101 website years ago, RIP indeed old friend.  Thanks for your help with this, I appreciate it.

Comment: Cheers @tamak and I too grew up in there with over 30,000 posts until they sold the place. Guess everything comes to an end, be it good or bad! :)

Answer (score 1):

Not without introducing alternative technologies for the sorting - the FileSystemObject.Files property doesn't support any sorting semantics.

A JScript solution seems like it could do an insertion sort fairly painlessly, though.